# Gps tracking application data send methods

Tags: android, gps

I want to create client-server GPS tracking application that clients send location data to server and server saves them on database and show clients location fleet location for site users and give report for them.
In this application i don't know which method i can use.Client applications is android apps and server application is web based application.
Methods for send data from clients to server:
1)Consume web service in clients and send data to server by means of web service
2)Use MQTT in client application and send data with MQTT
in 1st method because data is little when a web service want to send that data to server use XML and this can increase data sizes! and web server for obtain location data first need to decompress them and get location data from web service package that this can use server resources!.But method 2st send location data direct to server but hard to implement and encoding!
which of the methods you offer for me to use in this application?
another concern is if i want to scale this application for other client side platforms like iphone which of above methods is optimum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you thought on using a REST service instead ?
So your tracking device will basically just call a REST url and POST data to it.
No overload of data size or compression.
Same REST service can be consumed by an Android or iPhone app.

Comment: Ok thanks for your help.Can i encode data that sends from clients to server when i use RESTFUl?